# UIImageView auto resize inside a custom UITableViewCell with varying height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, custom-cell

I have set up a custom cell prototype inside storyboard not using autolayout and i have run into a rather vexing problem where a UIImageView i have inside the cell seems to obey constraints all of it's own when i want it to reflect the size of the cell with a bit of padding.

Here is the setup in storyboard interface builder and view mode is set to "scale to fill"

[image: Setup]

And here is what i get back, with no editing of the placement or scaling of the image, it seems very much like it's using aspect fill.

[image: Result]

I have tried various options and none seem to work for me so far, The only other way i can think is turn of auto resizing and set the rect myself manually when the cell is created any ideas?

and my code for setting the cell

```
- (void)setCell:(NSDictionary*)messageData
{
    [_nameLabel setText:messageData[@"name"]];
    [_messageLabel setText:messageData[@"message"]];

    [_nameLabel sizeToFit];
    [_messageLabel sizeToFit];

    UIImage *image;
    if([messageData[@"direction"] boolValue])
    {
        image= [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble_left"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 6, 6, 10) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
    }
    else
    {
        image= [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble_right"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 10, 6, 6) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
    }

    [_bubbleImage setImage:image];
}
```

and the protocol methods

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CUIChatCellTableViewCell *cell = [_chatTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *messageData = _testDataArray[indexPath.row];

    [cell setCell:messageData];

    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _customCell = [_chatTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

    //configure cell
    NSDictionary *messageData = _testDataArray[indexPath.row];

    [_customCell setCell:messageData];

    //Get height of the cell
    CGFloat height = [_customCell.messageLabel frame].size.height+[_customCell.nameLabel frame].size.height+20;

    return height;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get AutoResizing to work and i tried another test project from scratch and it seemed to work, so it must have been certain settings, either way i ended up having to set the height manually for each cell based on it's content anyway here is the code to do so

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

    //configure cell
    CMessageInfo *messageData = _testDataArray[indexPath.row];

    [_customCell setCell:messageData];

    //Get height of the cell
    CGFloat height = [_customCell.messageLabel frame].size.height+[_customCell.nameLabel frame].size.height+20;

    return height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set autoresizing properties like this, may you get help from this.

[image: Autoresizing]